# Can I configure or adapt ExSheets in order to distinguish "problems" from "exercises", each type being independently counted?

Tags: numbering, naming, exercises, exsheets

For reasons that are beside the point, I want to have both exercises,

Ex. 1.1, Ex. 1.2, Ex. 1.3, ...,

and problems

Prob. 1.1, Prob. 1.2, Prob. 1.3, ...

Maybe also Example 1.1, Example 1.2, ...

Problems will most usually come at the end of the chapter, after all exercises of that chapter, but I may intercalate them sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible with `exsheets` (and isn't going to be) but `exsheets`' [official successor package `xsim`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsim) natively supports this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseType{problem}{
  exercise-env = problem ,
  solution-env = answer ,
  exercise-name = Prob. ,
  solution-name = Answer ,
  exercise-template = default ,
  solution-template = default
}
\DeclareExerciseType{example}{
  exercise-env = example ,
  solution-env = hint ,
  exercise-name = Example ,
  solution-name = Hint ,
  exercise-template = default ,
  solution-template = default
}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name = Ex. ,
  exercise/within = section ,
  exercise/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{exercise} ,
  problem/within  = section ,
  problem/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{problem} ,
  example/within = section ,
  example/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{example}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\begin{exercise}
\end{exercise}

\begin{problem}
\end{problem}

\begin{exercise}
\end{exercise}

\begin{example}
\end{example}

\begin{exercise}
\end{exercise}

\begin{problem}
\end{problem}

\begin{example}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]